# how to setup multiple SMTP email servers primary & backup in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, email-client

I am trying to develop a email client. which sends email to the given recipients

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;    


MailMessage msg;
SmtpClient client;
SMTPURL=abc.xyz
SMTPPort=87
client = new SmtpClient(SMTPURL, SMTPPort);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPWD);
msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("rx@gmail.com");
msg.Body="hello hi bye";
client.Send(msg);
```

this code is working well, but I have a backup email server with URL 123.xyz

if my abc.xyz is down or I have wrong url I will get a SMTPException

Now my question is how to reroute my message  to 123.xyz backup mail server

**My assumption is to catch the SMTPException and change the SMTPURL to 123.xyz and resend, but is this a good way or any other alternates exists to reroute to secondary mail server ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use your basic try/catch block:

```
public void function sendemail()
{
try{
SendEmailByServer(primaryserverurl);
}
catch(SMTPException se)
{
sendemailbyserver(backupurl);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//something else broke
}

}

public void function SendEmailByServer(string server)
{
MailMessage msg;
SmtpClient client;
SMTPURL=server;
SMTPPort=87;
client = new SmtpClient(SMTPURL, SMTPPort);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPWD);
msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("rx@gmail.com");
msg.Body="hello hi bye";
client.Send(msg);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this helps. but  I wonder if there is something like C# inbuilt properties to setup prime and backup email server

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything in built. Most places I worked had their own exchange server, so if it was down you typically focused on bringing it back up rather than switching to a back up. You could always make your custom smtpclient that inherits from the .net one and then add the backup server as a property. Override the send method so that it does try base.send, catch & send with the backup maybe.